azure devtest labs - do existing resources need to be recreated?
We have many development and uat objects running in azure, not availing of devtest pricing.
I will be creating a subscription with devtest enabled, with a plan to move our resources over.
Do the resources (VM's, webapps, logic apps, ADF) need to be recreated to avail of the discount devtest pricing, or do they get the discount pricing by virtue of being in a subscription flagged for devtest?
